# Cannot get some kind of links parsing an HTML page with jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Given this link:

http://www.argenteam.net/movie/40749/American.Reunion.%282012%29

I'm trying to get all links like this on that page using jsoup:

```
<a href="ed2k://|file|American.Reunion.UNRATED.DVDRip.XviD.CD1-COCAIN.avi|734205866|C92C5188830C4F740C69521F67337A45|h=Z5F72XEXRGGXBCMSOR6NS3IBCTFIHQLL|/">CD1</a>
```

The problem is that I cannot get this kind of links.
Doing some extreme thing I've tried the following code to get all the links on the page, but again, this "a[href]" is not present on the list.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.******.net/movie/40749/American.Reunion.%282012%29").get();

Elements ed2k = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element emule:ed2k){
            String mula = emule.attr("href");
           }
```

How can I get all links beginning with value "ed2k"? They're on the CSS "div.pmovie div.releases div.release-info div.section div.links div a" but I don't know what is the problem, they're "invisible" for my implementations.
If you look into the source HTML code, it doesn't seem quirked and all browser can manage very well that kind of links. So, why I'm not reaching them parsing with jsoup and css selectors? Do I need to use Nodes and siblings?

Thanks in advance.

**Final edit with solution:**

The website was requesting a cookie to show the links I needed, since that cookie is only generated using a real browser, Jsoup wasn't capable to retrieve all the information and it was connecting to a reduced version of the real page. Sending the specific cookie in the Jsoup connection solved the issue. 
Example:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(your url here).cookie(cookie name, cookie value).get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any such links in the source of the url you specified.

In general you can do what you are asking using the following attribute value selection syntax:

```
[attr^=valPrefix] 
elements with an attribute named "attr", and value starting with "valPrefix"    
Example: a[href^=http:]
```

(From http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: Tried that before, but didn't work. My quick guess is that it seems like not all the links are not present in "doc" after connection. Check the CSS route "html body div#container div#contents div#wrapper div.pmovie div.releases div.release-info div.section div.links div a" and you will find this links.

Comment: @Tincho: I've got to agree with yotam -- there's no link similar to what you've posted in your question in the site you've provided the link to. 1+ to yotam's answer for useful jsoup recommendations.

Comment: Sorry, but the links are there. You can check the "elinks" sections navigating the page with a browser, or simply checking the source HTML. Yotam answer is the way to go if the source HTML is loaded OK into the "doc" object. But this is not the case here.

Comment: Mmmm, an advance. It seems that the page has a session or cookie system requesting a previous authorization to check the links I'm needing, so you both are right, maybe I need to programatically simulate that previous state (maybe in headers sent?) to reach the links with Jsoup that I'm already seeing in the normal browser.

Comment: That's it. Thanks to point the absence for you of the links!. It was a cookie. I solved sending it like this: doc = Jsoup.connect(url).cookie("tca", "Y").get();